# How to fix RegExp that keeps returning false?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var num = $("#phone").val();
var exp = new RegExp("((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}");

if (exp.test(num) === false)
{
  alert("***-***-**** or (***) ***-**** form only");
  return false;
}
```

When I enter "123-123-1234" or "(123) 123-1234", it will return false even though when I use a tester online, it comes back a match which to my understanding should be true. Can I get some advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to escape the backslash in a string: `new RegExp("((\\(\\d{3}\\) ?)|(\\d{3}-))?\\d{3}-\\d{4}");`. Or just use a regex literal: `var exp = /((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}/;`.

Comment: Here is a 20 minutes tutorial (https://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/learn-regular-expressions-in-20-minutes) help you to understand regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) literal.

```
var num = $("#phone").val();

if (!/((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(num)) {
  alert("***-***-**** or (***) ***-**** form only");
  return false;
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/g4fQgA/1 (see tests)